# EXC_BAD_ACCESS SpriteKit scene transition, no Zombies

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, exc-bad-access, skscene, nszombie

I am having a crash caused by `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.  It is not caught by setting the `NSZombieEnabled` to YES, indicating it isn't a freed object. (boy, do I really wish it was)

The stack trace is less than helpful (to me). Does anyone see any insight in it?

[image: bad address]

[image: stack trace]

```
SpriteKit`std::__1::__tree_iterator<SKCSprite*, std::__1::__tree_node<SKCSprite*, void*>*, long> std::__1::__tree<SKCSprite*, std::__1::less<SKCSprite*>, std::__1::allocator<SKCSprite*> >::find<SKCSprite*>:
    0x1890c376c <+0>:  ldr    x9, [x0, #8]!
    0x1890c3770 <+4>:  cbz    x9, 0x1890c37b8           ; <+76>
    0x1890c3774 <+8>:  ldr    x10, [x1]
    0x1890c3778 <+12>: mov    x8, x0
->  0x1890c377c <+16>: ldr    x11, [x9, #32]
    0x1890c3780 <+20>: cmp    x11, x10
    0x1890c3784 <+24>: b.hs   0x1890c3794               ; <+40>
    0x1890c3788 <+28>: ldr    x9, [x9, #8]
    0x1890c378c <+32>: cbnz   x9, 0x1890c377c           ; <+16>
    0x1890c3790 <+36>: b      0x1890c37a0               ; <+52>
    0x1890c3794 <+40>: mov    x8, x9
    0x1890c3798 <+44>: ldr    x9, [x9]
    0x1890c379c <+48>: cbnz   x9, 0x1890c377c           ; <+16>
    0x1890c37a0 <+52>: cmp    x8, x0
    0x1890c37a4 <+56>: b.eq   0x1890c37b8               ; <+76>
    0x1890c37a8 <+60>: ldr    x9, [x1]
    0x1890c37ac <+64>: ldr    x10, [x8, #32]
    0x1890c37b0 <+68>: cmp    x9, x10
    0x1890c37b4 <+72>: b.hs   0x1890c37bc               ; <+80>
    0x1890c37b8 <+76>: mov    x8, x0
    0x1890c37bc <+80>: mov    x0, x8
    0x1890c37c0 <+84>: ret
```

Other context:

SpriteKit application that is transitioning to a new scene. The new scene gets initially displayed but the crash occurs right away.

There is an action on both incoming and outgoing scenes. These actions contain a block that references the scene. The scenes were leaking and this block seemed to be one of the offenders. When I added code to remove the action, this crash emerged.

Xcode 6.4
iPad Air, iOS 8.4.1

---

**Edit 1**: 
This code exists on each SKScene.
When the second method is commented out it *hides* the problem (i believe by aiding the leak).

```
- (void)startAutoScore {
  // as long as you survive, you gradually accumulate points
  SKAction *autoScore = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    [self adjustScoreBy:1];
  }];

  NSTimeInterval duration = 0.25;
  SKAction *slice = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:duration], autoScore]];
  SKAction *repeat = [SKAction repeatAction:slice count:self.fieldDescriptor.duration / duration - 1];
  [self runAction:repeat withKey:@"autoScore"];
}

- (void)stopAutoScore {
//  [self removeActionForKey:@"autoScore"];
}
```

---

**Edit 2**: I have confirmed with Instruments that when the `stopAutoScore` method is executed, the last remaining reference to the used `SKScene` is removed and the old scene is correctly deallocated.

Comment: Can you update a question with the actual code (the part you think its relevant), just for completeness because that way its more likely that you will get better answer.

Comment: I cannot know what part of my code is the salient part. See the first image. It is breaking in `main()`, and the stack trace is an unsymbolized machine code internal to `SpriteKit`. I would love to have some code associated with it.

Comment: @whirlwind i added some code but don't believe it is causing the problem, rather hiding it, when the scene "stops early" and the code is not commented out, the crashes will occur

Comment: Okay, I will look at it closer later when I get in front of computer... The only thing I can see is that maybe you have possible retain cycle. Try to override scene's dealloc method and see if it is called (do this in both scenes as well).

Comment: Can you set uncaught exception handler in AppDelegate and see if you get some error there? Put following above @implementation AppDelegate: static void UncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exc) {
    NSLog(@"%@", exc.callStackSymbols);
}
And this in didFinishLaunching: NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&UncaughtExceptionHandler);

Comment: @bshirley- Try setting an All Exceptions breakpoint and see where in your code the error happens.

Comment: @Josip, That gives me the same information the debugger is providing.

Comment: @sangony, I did already have the All Exceptions breakpoint set.

Answer (score 0):

I have a current (less than ideal) **workaround**.

If I convert the transition out of the particularly complex `SKScene` into a straight `presentScene:`

from:

```
SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithColor:[SKColor whiteColor] duration:1.0];
[self.view presentScene:scene transition:transition];
```

to:

```
[self.view presentScene:scene];
```

*and* if I explicitly remove all the children from the scene about to be replaced *before* I call the 'presentScene'

```
[self removeAllChildren];
```

Then the crashes (which were non-deterministic, but common, occurring at least by the 4th such transition) halt.

Given that, I would consider this a bug internal to SpriteKit, or some way I am mismanaging sprites. I would love to have a correct answer.